# URL adding www when loading site, and not https://

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I am unable to get my WordPress website to initially load without www and with https:// instead of http://.

I set the WordPress permalinks to "Post name", so the url looks like "https://example.com/sample-post". I also changed the "WordPress Address (URL)" and "Site Address (URL)" to "https://example.com".

I added this to the wp-config.php:

```
define( 'FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true );
```

Nothing works.

One thing I did that sort of worked was adding this to .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

And it will initially load my website as www.example.com, then 3 seconds later change it to https://example.com. This seems like a weird hack.

What am I missing? How do I have my website initially load normally with https://

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: I would think this would only apply when clicking on the link from Google. When physically typing example.com into the address bar, it becomes www.example.com. The inner links go to https:// example.com, but I'm trying to get the site on page load to go to https:// example.com.

Comment: Edited my answer to suit your needs. Hope this helps.

Comment: Where about should I add that? I already have something like that in my htaccess file. I wrote it out in original post.

Comment: Remove your top one and add the one I posted.

Comment: It's doing the same thing for me. It hangs on www.example.com for 2-3 seconds, and then rewrites the url to https://example.com

Comment: Sorry, i meant to say it rewrites the url from www. to https:// example.com after 3 seconds.